# JTable auto row sorter index of sorting column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I'm trying to make a custom row header renderer, to change the color of the header to for example red, of the column that's table is sorted by. this part I managed by renderer from this tutorial [JTable column header custom renderer examples](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jtable-column-header-custom-renderer-examples) and invoking:

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexOfColumn);

column.setHeaderRenderer(new KeepSortIconHeaderRenderer(
    table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()));
```

For sorting, I use auto row sorter. I need to get the index of the column that the user sorted by so I can pass that index to the code above. Is there any fuction I can use? Closest I managed to get is overriding  toggleSortOrder but that override the whole auto row sorter so it's stopped working.

Comment: You can try [getting the column index by the column name](http://www.java2s.com/example/java/swing/get-jtable-column-index-from-name.html).

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].